# Linking terminal server profiles with roaming possible?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, group-policy, terminal-server, user-profile

I'm having a hard time setting up a few roaming profiles.

I've a user who uses our terminal server but we want him to start using his local computer on the domain. This part I know how to do. I've created a roaming profile, shared folders, etc. The problem is when the user goes home and works at home he remotes to the server and it starts going off the terminal server profile.

- Ex. Roaming profile to to C:\profiles
- Ex  Terminal profile C:\document and settings\User.

Is there any way to merge or link these? So if my user logs on in the office on the domain he will have the same profile as when he goes home and works. ex same emails, docs, etc

This user is a test for now; we are trying to get users in the office to stop working off the term server since it's running so slow.

Answer (score 1):

Server 2008 uses a Vista/Win7-style ".V2" profile; Server 2003 uses an XP-style profile.

Use folder redirection for Documents, and get as much out of the roaming profiles as possible.

Comment: why? how else do you get user profiles to look the same? My users hate change and they're used to remote login

Comment: @user Set expectations appropriately for your users. Managing their experience to the point where they can't discern change is expensive, make sure they understand that. If they still want it, deliver. Otherwise help them to understand the change as best you can.